# Evaluation of functional derivative of effective action

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, functional-derivatives, 1pi-effective-action

I'm trying to understand a calculation in appendix A of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.04197, however I don't understand how they end up with equation (125) and I think I am going wrong in the functional derivative.

They are computing $\frac{\delta^3 W[J]}{\delta J^\mu(x)\,\delta\eta(y)\,\delta\bar{\eta}(z)}$ for QED, where $W[J]$ is the generating functional and $J^\mu,\,\eta,\,\bar{\eta}$ are the sources. I have omitted the Latin indices they use in the paper as they don't affect the problem I'm having.

They start from the following equation
$$\frac{\delta\Gamma}{\delta\bar{\psi} (x)}=-\eta(x),$$

where $\Gamma$ is the effective action that depends on the classical fields $\psi,\bar{\psi},A_\mu$.

They then say we need to take a derivative first w.r.t $\eta$ and then take one w.r.t $A_\mu$.

First doing $\eta$ I get
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\eta(y)}\left(\frac{\delta\Gamma}{\delta\bar{\psi} (x)}+\eta(x)\right)=0$$
$$=\int_z\left(\frac{\delta\bar{\psi}(z)}{\delta\eta(y)}\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\bar{\psi}(x)\delta\bar{\psi}(z)}+\frac{\delta\psi(z)}{\delta\eta(y)}\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}+\frac{\delta A_\nu(z)}{\delta\eta(y)}\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\bar{\psi}(x)\delta A_\nu(z)}\right)+\delta(x-y)=0$$

Next we should take the functional derivative w.r.t $A_\mu$. The only non-zero term after setting the sources to $0$ will be the second one, so focusing on that we are taking

$$\int_z\frac{\delta}{\delta A_\mu (w)}\left(\frac{\delta\psi(z)}{\delta\eta(y)}\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}\right)=0.$$

I use the chain rule to write the above as

$$\int_z\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}\frac{\delta}{\delta A_\mu (w)}\left(\frac{\delta\psi(z)}{\delta\eta(y)}\right)+\int_z\frac{\delta\psi(z)}{\delta\eta(y)}\frac{\delta}{\delta A_\mu (w)}\left(\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}\right)=0,$$

$$=\int_z\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}\frac{\delta^2\psi(z)}{\delta A_\mu (w)\delta\eta(y)}+\int_z\frac{\delta\psi(z)}{\delta\eta(y)}\,\frac{\delta^3\Gamma}{\delta A_\mu (w)\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}.$$

Then using the definition $$\psi(x)=\frac{\delta W[J]}{\delta\bar{\eta}(x)}$$

I can write this as
$$\int_z\frac{\delta^2\Gamma}{\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}\frac{\delta^3 W[J]}{\delta A_\mu (w)\delta\eta(y)\delta\bar{\eta}(z)}+\int_z\frac{\delta^2W[J]}{\delta\eta(y)\delta\bar{\eta}(z)}\,\frac{\delta^3\Gamma}{\delta A_\mu (w)\delta\psi(z)\delta\bar{\psi}(x)}.$$

However this is incorrect as I should be getting equation (125) in the paper, so in particular the first term is wrong. I guess I am doing the functional derivatives incorrectly, but I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I realised the issue so I will just answer my own question.

The derivative
$$\frac{\delta^2\psi(z)}{\delta A_\mu(w) \delta \eta(y)},$$ appearing in the 3rd last equation should in fact be written as
$$\int_u\frac{\delta J_\nu(u)}{\delta A_\mu(w)}\frac{\delta^2\psi(z)}{ \delta \eta(y)\delta J_\nu(u)}.$$

Then using the definitions $$J_\nu(x)=-\frac{\delta \Gamma}{\delta A_\nu(x)},$$
and $$\psi(x)=\frac{\delta W}{\delta\bar{\eta}(x)},$$

we will end up with the correct expression.

$$$$